# get the json from android php mysql data insert application

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

This is my android json response for `php mysql` data insert application. please help me to get the original json from this return response 
or how to skip return web (HTML) table from return response
(`data success fully inserting to the data base table`)

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\AndroidFileUpload\db_connect.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>252784</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\AndroidFileUpload\upload_news.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\upload_news.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>263888</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_CONNECT->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\AndroidFileUpload\upload_news.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\upload_news.php<b>:</b>26</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>263976</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_CONNECT->connect(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\AndroidFileUpload\db_connect.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\db_connect.php<b>:</b>11</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>264792</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\AndroidFileUpload\db_connect.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\db_connect.php<b>:</b>28</td></tr>
</table></font>

{"success":1,"message":"Product successfully created."}
```

at the last line of the response have needed json result.
any help appreciate.
thanks in advance.

here is my `php` code

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['news_Title']) && isset($_POST['news_Details']) && isset($_POST['news_Image'])&& isset($_POST['news_Video']) && isset($_POST['reporter_Name']) && isset($_POST['reporter_Email']) && isset($_POST['reporter_Phone'])) {

    $news_Title = $_POST['news_Title'];
    $news_Details = $_POST['news_Details'];
    $news_Image = $_POST['news_Image'];
    $news_Video = $_POST['news_Video'];
    $reporter_Name = $_POST['reporter_Name'];
    $reporter_Email = $_POST['reporter_Email'];
    $reporter_Phone = $_POST['reporter_Phone'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(news_Title, news_Details, news_Image, news_Video, reporter_Name, reporter_Email , reporter_Phone) VALUES('$news_Title', '$news_Details', '$news_Image', '$news_Video', '$reporter_Name', '$reporter_Email', '$reporter_Phone')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: post your php code also.

Comment: is html part of response always same?

Comment: There is problem with your service having some warnings about deprecated methods, resolve it first.

Comment: The `mysql` extension in deprecated. Please use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @Arjun php code posted

Comment: Change to `mysqli_connect()` in `db_connect.php` file, also in production turn off error reporting by setting `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: im really new to php. 'mysql_select_db()'  and  'mysql_close();' should be 'mysqli_select_db()'  and 'mysqli_close();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply i solved my problem by using tricky way. but this is not the exact correct way to solve this.

```
String jsonStrObj = strReturn.substring(strReturn.lastIndexOf('{') + 1);
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStrObj);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

Waiting for the correct answer..
thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in response. Your mysql_connect() function will deprecated in future version of php
Use msyqli.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
?>
```

or turn off all deprecated warnings including them from mysql_*:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
?>
```